# Repetitive HTTP requests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Every 30 seconds within my application, I would like to make HTTP request to my second server. I would like to write the result into the database.

I am relatively new to Ruby and Rails, and I am not sure what is a standard way to accomplish this.
Should I use some kind or timer? Loop?
Should it be in model of my application? Or somewhere else?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maintain a heartbeat? Are you keeping the records? Is this for notification if something goes wrong? There are all sorts of tools available and it sounds like you're reinventing several wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of [screencasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32) for running background jobs in rails. Once you've decided how you're going to implement it, you can do everything you need to with the ruby standard library. Just use the [http library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).

You can write the results to a db like [SQLite](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/) or whatever your application is using.

Comment: If you put this in an application, the processing will hang indefinitely. For it to work it needs to be in a thread, or forked.

Comment: @the Tin Man, you're absolutely right. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you, @Sunny Juneja and the Tin Man! It is a great help!